# matrix multiplication using star operator

Tags: pytorch

I am curious about what the difference is between calling torch.mm(A, B) and A*B?

Looks like torch.mm gives us the desirable result, but A*B sometimes doesn't work.

It will be better if any documentation is provided.

Thank you!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`torch.mm(A,B)` is a regular matrix multiplication and `A*B` is element-wise multiplication. You can read it on this [discussion](https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/the-differences-between-torch-mul-a-b-and-a-b/32153). For matrix multiplication you can use `@` if I am not mistaken as well.

Comment: You are correct, you can use the `@` operator as well.